# Netplan not bringing up interface

Tags: ethernet, netplan, lan

Having issues with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10 to manage wired network.
During install it would detect 4 ports, and I configured one with DHCP and disabled all others. It's a very simple configuration, the wire is always connected and will serve a DHCP address, but everytime I boot the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` fails.

My motherboard is a SuperMicro X9DRI-LN4F with 4 on-board ports.

When booting up the device I see the following:

```
Jan 31 13:28:46 labNode1 systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Network.
Jan 31 13:28:46 labNode1 systemd[1]: Starting Network Configuration...
Jan 31 13:28:47 labNode1 systemd[1]: Started Network Configuration.
Jan 31 13:28:47 labNode1 systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jan 31 13:28:47 labNode1 systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Jan 31 13:29:15 labNode1 systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 31 13:30:47 labNode1 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 31 13:30:47 labNode1 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 31 13:30:47 labNode1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
Jan 31 13:30:47 labNode1 systemd[1]: Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...
Jan 31 13:30:49 labNode1 systemd[1]: Finished Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).
Jan 31 13:30:49 labNode1 systemd[1]: Reached target Cloud-config availability.
Jan 31 13:30:49 labNode1 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jan 31 13:30:49 labNode1 systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
```

**/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eth3:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

I also see that udev tries to rename devices and sometimes upon rebooting my connected **eth3 link becomes eno1** (same MAC address) and eth3 disappears.

```
Jan 31 13:28:44 labNode1 systemd-udevd[764]: eno1: Failed to rename network interface 3 from 'eth1' to 'eno1': File exists
Jan 31 13:28:44 labNode1 systemd-udevd[797]: eno1: Failed to rename network interface 4 from 'eth2' to 'eno1': File exists
Jan 31 13:28:44 labNode1 systemd-udevd[794]: eno1: Failed to rename network interface 5 from 'eth3' to 'eno1': File exists
Jan 31 13:28:44 labNode1 systemd-udevd[764]: eno1: Failed to process device, ignoring: File exists
Jan 31 13:28:44 labNode1 systemd-udevd[797]: eno1: Failed to process device, ignoring: File exists
Jan 31 13:28:44 labNode1 systemd-udevd[794]: eno1: Failed to process device, ignoring: File exists
```

Once the system fully boots when I login and do a `ip link show` and my `eth3` shows as down.

```
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2d:d3:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp6s0f0
3: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2d:d3:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp6s0f1
4: eth2:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2d:d3:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp6s0f2
5: eth3:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2d:d3:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp6s0f3
6: docker0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:b4:b0:a2:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I have to manually run these steps to get it back online and it works every time.

`sudo ip link set dev eth3 up`

`sudo dhclient`

I've tried about everything I can think of, even the aliases in netplan.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      optional: true
    eth0:
      optional: true
    eth2:
      optional: true
    eth3:
      dhcp4: true
    enp6s0f0:
      optional: true
    enp6s0f1:
      optional: true
    enp6s0f2:
      optional: true
    enp6s0f3:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Here's the output of `networkctl` (after manually bringing up the eth3 interface)

```
IDX LINK    TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo      loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eno1    ether    no-carrier  configuring
  3 eth1    ether    no-carrier  pending
  4 eth2    ether    no-carrier  pending
  5 eth3    ether    routable    pending
  6 docker0 bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged

6 links listed.
```

`journalctl -t systemd-networkd`

```
-- Boot e8c567961a2c4c0ea500fdb90029eccb --
Feb 01 14:53:40 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: lo: Link UP
Feb 01 14:53:40 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: lo: Gained carrier
Feb 01 14:53:40 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: Enumeration completed
Feb 01 14:53:40 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: eno1: Configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eno1.network.
Feb 01 14:53:40 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: eno1: Link UP
Feb 01 14:53:42 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: docker0: Link UP
Feb 01 14:54:02 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: eno1: Gained carrier
Feb 01 14:54:04 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: eno1: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 01 15:11:19 labNode1 systemd-networkd[1005]: eno1: DHCPv6 lease lost
```